# download the file from outside of the ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, download

I have a files in my server the following location. "/home/files/*.doc". My Project location is "/home/bld/.." Is there way to download the doc file from the folder "/home/files/x.doc" using the ruby code. The documents folder is located from outside of my project folder,

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be an issue simply doing:

```
send_file('/home/files/*.doc')
```

No?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to **download** it while it is on the same computer. You need to copy it

```
Dir['/home/files/*.doc'].each do |file|
  File.cp file, "/home/bld/public/my_docs" # /home/bld/public/my_docs can be any dir
end
```